# Strip overlay context from File field

Tags: 7, files

I have a basic File field set up to allow my users to attach files to nodes.

However, the File field widget in the node edit form displays files as a link to the file, and the URL contains `#overlay-context=`. Thus when users right click to copy the URL to the file, the URL includes the overlay context, and the link doesn't work (or images don't display).

How do I stop the Overlay module from adding that on to the File URLs on the node edit form?

I have the [Insert](http://drupal.org/project/insert) module, [IMCE](http://drupal.org/project/imce), and [IMCE WYSIWYG bridge](http://drupal.org/project/imce_wysiwyg) enabled to provide users with other options, but some users (including myself) still prefer to right click the file name and copy the URL.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of offhand is to play with [hook_url_outbound_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_url_outbound_alter/7) and make a regex to alter only the file paths url in question (not just any and all urls on the site) and strip out the context.

There might be a better way to do this ... maybe like theme_link or theme_links overridden for the given region ?